# Calculate row sums conditional on column with 1 and 0's in a data frame in R , want the sum between consecutive 1's between 0's

Tags: r, sum, aggregate, subset, subset-sum

Input data frame reproducible example:

```
onoff = c(0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0)
amount = c(0,0.5,0,0.6,0,0,0.5,0.6,0.7,0)

mockdata = data.frame(onoff, amount)
```

It looks like this.

[image: picture of dataframe]

I want to sum the sequence of rows where `onoff` is 1 between 0's. 
So in this example, I'd have two sets of sums, the first between rows 2 and 4, and the second between rows 7 and 9. 
So I would output two numbers, 1.1 and 1.8.

Not sure how to do this, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: if onoff=0 then we can assume amount is also 0?

Answer (score 3):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table` to create a grouping column and then use that to get the `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
mockdata %>% 
   group_by(grp = rleid(onoff)) %>% 
   mutate(Sum = sum(amount) * onoff)
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   grp [5]
#   onoff amount   grp   Sum
#   <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <dbl>
# 1     0    0       1   0  
# 2     1    0.5     2   1.1
# 3     1    0       2   1.1
# 4     1    0.6     2   1.1
# 5     0    0       3   0  
# 6     0    0       3   0  
# 7     1    0.5     4   1.8
# 8     1    0.6     4   1.8
# 9     1    0.7     4   1.8
#10     0    0       5   0
```

---

If we need a summarised output

```
mockdata %>% 
  group_by(grp = rleid(onoff)) %>% 
  filter(onoff == 1) %>% 
  summarise(amount = sum(amount))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
aggregate(mockdata$amount, list(grp = c(1, cumsum(diff(mockdata$onoff) == 1))), sum)

      grp   x
1       1 1.1
2       2 1.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base R, we can use `rle` to create groups and `tapply` to calculate summarised data

```
with(rle(mockdata$onoff != 1), tapply(mockdata$amount, 
           rep(cumsum(values), lengths), sum))

#  1   2   3 
#1.1 1.8 0.0
```

---

Or another approach which I think is closer to expected output is to filter the rows with `onoff = 1`

```
mockdata$row <- seq_len(nrow(mockdata))
temp <- subset(mockdata, onoff == 1)
tapply(temp$amount, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(temp$row) > 1)), sum)

#  1   2 
#1.1 1.8
```